# qsort in C is an unexpected bottle neck in my program

Tags: c

I am working on some code to align astronomical images.  I am writing it in C99.  For some reason, my algorithm for detecting the stars in an image was running much slower than expected.  I basically need to ignore all pixels which are below the 99th percentile (because stars are just small bright points).  To calculate the 99th percentile I applied a `qsort` to a copy of the pixels in the image.  When I profiled the code, it said that it was spending 75% of the time executing the `compare_quantum` function used by qsort.  The entire detection of stars takes about 3 seconds.

I had originally written the code in C++ and the same algorithm took about 0.2 seconds. I am guessing that the reason this is happening is that unlike C++, C can't just inline the call to the compare function like C++ can with `std::sort`.

I could write my own sort function, but I was just wondering if anyone had any other ideas to make this go faster.  I have calls to qsort elsewhere in the code and I am thinking maybe I need to get rid of all of them.

I am using gcc 5.2.  The first qsort in `stars_map` is the bottle neck.  Also `quantum_t` is just a typedef for `uint16_t`.

```
int compare_quantum(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return (*(quantum_t*)a > *(quantum_t*)b) - (*(quantum_t*)a < *(quantum_t*)b);
}

void star_register(quantum_t* grey, double* rowint, double* colint, double* lum, size_t row, size_t col, size_t w, size_t h)
{
    size_t gi = row * w + col;
    if(!(row >= 0 && col >= 0 && row < h && col < w && grey[gi]))
        return;

    *rowint += grey[gi] * row;
    *colint += grey[gi] * col;
    *lum += grey[gi];
    grey[gi] = 0;

    for(int dr = -1; dr <= 1; dr++)
    {
        for(int dc = -1; dc <= 1; dc++)
        {
            if(dc == 0 && dr == 0)
                continue;
            star_register(grey, rowint, colint, lum, row + dr, col + dc, w, h);
        }
    }
}

stars_t* stars_map(image_t* img, float detection_percentile)
{
    assert(img);

    quantum_t* grey = NULL;
    quantum_t* sorted = NULL;
    star_t* stars = NULL;
    size_t nstars = 0;
    size_t stars_alloc = 0;

    grey = malloc(sizeof(quantum_t) * img->w * img->h);
    if(grey == NULL) goto fail;

    sorted = malloc(sizeof(quantum_t) * img->w * img->h);
    if(sorted == NULL) goto fail;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < img->w * img->h; i++)
        sorted[i] = grey[i] = ((uint32_t)img->px[i].red + (uint32_t)img->px[i].green + (uint32_t)img->px[i].blue) / 3;
    //this qsort is the issue
    qsort(sorted, img->w * img->h, sizeof(quantum_t), compare_quantum);
    quantum_t cut = sorted[(size_t)(img->w * img->h * detection_percentile)];
    free(sorted);
    sorted = NULL;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < img->w * img->h; i++)
        grey[i] = clampq((int32_t)grey[i] - cut);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < img->h; i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < img->w; j++)
        {
            if(grey[i * img->w + j])
            {
                if(nstars == stars_alloc)
                {
                    stars = realloc(stars, (stars_alloc += 500) * sizeof(star_t));
                    if(!stars) goto fail;
                }
                double rowint = 0.0;
                double colint = 0.0;
                double lum = 0.0;
                star_register(grey, &rowint, &colint, &lum, i, j, img->w, img->h);
                stars[nstars++] = (star_t){.x = colint / lum, .y = rowint / lum, .lum = lum};
            }
        }
    }

    free(grey);

    qsort(stars, nstars, sizeof(star_t), star_compare);

    stars_t* result = malloc(sizeof(stars_t) + nstars * sizeof(star_t));
    if(result == NULL) goto fail;
    result->npairs = nstars;
    memcpy(result->stars, stars, sizeof(star_t) * nstars);
    free(stars);


    return result;

    fail:
    if(grey) free(grey);
    if(sorted) free(sorted);
    if(stars) free(stars);

    return NULL;
}
```

I originally thought that the recursive call to `star_register` would be the performance hit, but it barely matters in the profile.

Comment: If it worked fine in C++, why are you rewriting in C?

Comment: Its part of a bigger program which I have in C.

Comment: Why do you use `void *` as the parameter types in your `compare_quantum` function to then cast them internally into `quantum_t` types? Throwing away type information to then cast things creates unnecessary overhead, and this is where you say 75% of the time is spent.

Comment: What about if copy `qsort` from `glibc` sources and call compare function directly, does it make difference? http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c

Comment: @ray: because the C `qsort()` function requires a comparator that takes two `const void *` values.

Comment: I leave it as void because I get a warning if I don't. warning: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Comment: Also the void pointer makes not difference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Fair enough, but it seems that he was better off using the C++ implementation he had before, which could've performed better by preserving data type information and other details. His post made it sound like he had a C++ version of this working nicely already, so I'm not sure why he wanted to change it?

Comment: I think I just found the issue.  I forgot that I was using quick select not quick sort in c++.  That is why it is running so much faster.

Comment: Have you tried a good old-fashioned comparator such as: `int compare_quantum(const void* a, const void* b)
{ quantum_t q1 = *(quantum_t *)a; quantum_t q2 = *(quantum_t *)b; if (a < b) return -1; else if (a > b) return +1; else return 0; }`  — or, if `quantum_t` is a synonym for `uint16_t`, you can reduce that to: `int compare_quantum(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return *(quantum_t*)a - *(quantum_t*)b;
}` since the `qsort()` function doesn't require ±1 or 0 as the return.

Comment: So you should write your own `qselect()` in C, based on the `qsort()` interface.  That will be quicker.

Comment: I just did.  The code is now much faster.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had forgotten that I was using std::nth_element not std::sort in the c++ version.  That is why the code was slow.  I wrote a qselect and now the entire program is about the same speed.

```
quantum_t quantum_qselect(quantum_t *v, size_t len, size_t k)
{
    size_t i, st;

    for(st = i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        if(v[i] > v[len - 1])
            continue;
        swap(quantum_t, v[i], v[st]);
        st++;
    }

    swap(quantum_t, v[len - 1], v[st]);

    return k == st ? v[st] : st > k ? quantum_qselect(v, st, k) : quantum_qselect(v + st, len - st, k - st);
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have now discovered two reasons why it would be better to use C++ :) (You can call C++ non-member functions from C as long as you declare them with `extern "C"`, so maybe you can isolate the pixel identifying code in a C++ module.)